# How to achieve proper alpha blending using GDAL command line tools only

Tags: raster, gdal, pdf, mbtiles

With only using GDAL command line tools is it possible to avoid those white borders around edges of features?

I am using gdal_translate to convert vector PDF to raster mbtiles (OGR is not recognizing PDF format but GDAL does)

```
gdal_translate -of mbtiles --config GDAL_PDF_DPI 300 test.pdf test.mbtiles
gdalbuildvrt -srcnodata 255 output.vrt test.mbtiles
```

(I am using first `gdal_translate` with some `-gcp` points to georeference nonspatial-pdf but I have removed it here for easy reading)

I am getting this result:

[image: not correct]

but this is what I want:

[image: correct]

Comment: You could convert the pdf first to png or tiff, move the background to alpha with e.g. GIMPs color to alpha tool, then georeferencing. I have not found an easy solution with imagemagick to automate it ... Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26408022/imagemagick-color-to-alpha-like-the-gimp/26442085#26442085) will work.